# how to get the file of an image? in python ? django rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

```
class DemoAPIView(APIView):
    parser_classes = (JSONParser, FormParser, MultiPartParser)

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        data = request.data
        attached_file = request.FILES['attached_file']
        description_image = data.get('descriptionImage', None)
        attachment = dict(object_id=174, project=1, attached_file=attached_file,
                          description=description_image)
        header = {'Authorization': 'Bearer eyJ1c2VyX2F1dGhlbnRpY2F0aW9uX2lkIjoxNn0:1gSTf6:KbOb0yhqC-qVPTEPRoiVBBZjN6M'}
        r = requests.post('demo/api/v1/issues/attachments', data=attachment, headers=header)
        print(r.json())
        return Response({'error': 'ERROR XD'}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

and the error that the api booted me is the following:

```
{'attached_file': ['No file was submitted. Check the encoding type on the form.']}
```

which is the image that I sent from the client.
print the attached file and just show me the url, apparently that's the problem.
Is there any way to get the full file?

Form client:

```
const bodyFormData = new FormData();
            if (typeof this.image !== 'string') {
              bodyFormData.append('attached_file', this.image);
              bodyFormData.append('descriptionImage', this.descriptionImage);
            }
            this.axios.post('/api/', bodyFormData,
              { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' } })
              .then((response) => {
                this.isSending = false;
                this.$snackbar.open(response.data.results);
                this.feedback = {};
                this.image = {};
              }).catch((err) => {
                this.$snackbar.open({ message: err.response.data.error, type: 'is-danger' });
                this.isSending = false;
              });
```

Answer (score 1):

The submitted form probably is not `enctype="multipart/form-data`.

As stated in the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/file-uploads/):

> Note that **request.FILES** will only contain data if the request method was **POST** and the  that posted the request has the attribute **enctype="multipart/form-data"**. Otherwise, **request.FILES** will be empty.

For DRF, you probably want the FileUploadParser(see [this](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/parsers/#fileuploadparser))

Comment: If I am sending it in that format, I will update the question.

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck on the similar problem. I used an simple technique to solve (Using PATCH
instead of PUT) solved my problem.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31454911)